# Hive latest partition and count for multiple tables

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a requirement to find the latest partition and find total no of records for multiple tables.

Currently doing manually . Is their any best way to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Last partition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38150024/2700344

Comment: (1) Do you know for sure that the last partition defined holds data (sometimes partitions are defined in advance and filled with data later on) (2) Are you collecting statistics on the tables/added partitions? Do you add/remove filed without updating the statistics?

Comment: @ Dudu. I am looking to collect the statistics of the partitions.